# Cache control for images provided by an external script

Tags: apache, .htaccess

While developing a web project I want to profile this as often as I can but I'm using external image resources such as lorempixel.com with image urls such as: http://lorempixel.com/300/100/nature/6/

This is my htaccess file (relevant part):

```
<FilesMatch ".(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=3600, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

This however has no effect on the caching behavior of the provided url which makes sense to a certain extend. My question is how can I cache something like this at least for the time I'm developing the page. But instead of profiling after everything is done I like to do this during the development process as well. Warnings by profiling tools and horrendous loading times due to a slow respond (slow compared to if I would store the image locally) can get annoying.

I guess I don't have to tell you that using these sample images instead of local images which I may have to resize every time is way easier.

Maybe even a caching everything from lorempixel.com would be nice if this is possible. Usually someone else does this but now I'm on my own on this, so I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Caching instructions are send via HTTP headers – so they have to come with the HTTP response the server of lorempixel.com sends you. You only option here would be to set up your apache as a proxy server for certain URLs/domains, so that you could f.e. request `http://yourdomain.local/lorempixel.com/300/100/nature/6/` instead, and add caching information yourself in the process.

Comment: Or another way, without actually proxying by apache: Request `http://yourdomain.local/lorempixel.com/300/100/nature/6/` – if this exists as a local file already, have apache deliver that with your own caching headers, and if it does not already exists, rewrite the request to a script of some sort (PHP, PERL), that requests the image from their server and saves a local copy of it.

Comment: @CBroe Sounds smart, write it as answer and you'll get your accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or another way, without actually proxying by apache:

Request `http://yourdomain.local/lorempixel.com/300/100/nature/6/` – if this exists as a local file already, have apache deliver that with your own caching headers, and if it does not already exist, rewrite the request to a script of some sort (PHP, PERL), that requests the image from their server and saves a local copy of it.